# Reset GoogleAuthUtil so it will as for permission again

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using the google play services authentication example [here](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html)

How do I reset the GoogleAuthUtil so it will ask for permission again?

It asks for permission by throwing the userRecoverableException which is fed to a dialog.  But it only asks for permission one time.  I need to test asking for permission again.

I've tried to uninstall the sample app and re-install the sample app and this didn't work it doesn't ask for permission seems it already knows the app.

```
protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
        // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not
        // present, which is
        // recoverable, so we need to show the user some UI through the
        // activity.
        MyGooglePlay.handleException(userRecoverableException);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
        onError("Unrecoverable error " + fatalException.getMessage(),
                fatalException);
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * This method is a hook for background threads and async tasks that need to provide the
 * user a response UI when an exception occurs.
 */
public void handleException(final Exception e) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                // The Google Play services APK is old, disabled, or not present.
                // Show a dialog created by Google Play services that allows
                // the user to update the APK
                int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException)e)
                        .getConnectionStatusCode();
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode,
                        HelloActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                dialog.show();
            } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                // Unable to authenticate, such as when the user has not yet granted
                // the app access to the account, but the user can fix this.
                // Forward the user to an activity in Google Play services.
                Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException)e).getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Google Settings` app to de-authorize connected applications, by following these steps:

1. Launch the Google Settings app

[image: Google Settings App Icon]

2. Choose the `Connected apps` option (at the top)

[image: Google Settings options]

3. A list of connected apps is displayed; find the app you want to de-authorize and select it. Sorry there is no screenshot as I'm not able to remove personal info from it ATM - but it should be quite straightforward what to do here :)
4. Finally, click the `Disconnect` button (at the bottom) on the details page of the app

[image: Connected app details]

Note that it might take a moment before the app is de-authorized.

Comment: Try [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?hl=en) then.

Comment: Not enough granularity on that link.  It has a option to revoke from the hole phone.  and I don't want to mess the entire phone up just the one app.

Comment: I actually found the way to do this is to delete the account from the phone and then readd the account.  I'm past this now.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also call GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken or GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken, that should make it ask the permission again.

Comment: Maybe clear token will work I'll try it next time I'm back to this task.  I know what does work is removing the account from the device and then adding the account back to the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a user, like what free3dom answered, you can go to Google Settings app to revoke the access.

If you want to revoke the access programmatically, you can call Google's revoke token API: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke. Basically, you should first get a valid token with a set of scopes by calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`, and then revoke the token. After the token is revoked, you should see the permission dialog again.